# Navbar not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a follow up to my last post, I found a issue after putting the images on top not sure if this is directly related. The issue is where you can't click on the nav links as they are transparent.

Only one shows the hover color when the cursor is put in a specific position. None of them can be click other that one which only works in a specific position. They do not show the hover color.

Code:
*CODE HAS BEEN DELETED AS WEBSITE IS POSTED*

Comment: Two things - can you make a bootply? Can you format your code so at least it's readable without massive scrolling

Comment: @DarrenSweeney bootply was not working here is a codeply http://www.codeply.com/go/j799QcNiQ8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is located here:

```
div.staffimg {
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 205px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Instead of just positioning your element, you are creating a block element that covers your navigation as it extends to bottom of screen.

Remove the `left` and `bottom` properties to solve this:

```
div.staffimg {
    top: 100px;
    /* left: 0px; */
    right: 205px;
    /* bottom: 0px; */
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much would have never relized that mistake! Lol i thought  the 0px; meant it did nothing.